# Using Splinter to Enter String in Form

Tags: python, python-3.x, splinter

I am trying to enter a string into a form on an Amazon page. What am I doing wrong?

```
from splinter import Browser
import time

url = 'https://sellercentral.amazon.com/fba/profitabilitycalculator/index?lang=en_US'

executable_path = {'executable_path': 'chromedriver.exe'}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path, headless=False)

browser.visit(url)
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_by_id('search-form').first.type('Steve Jobs')
time.sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

**Update:**

I am able to click the form using:

```
browser.find_by_xpath(".//form//input[@type='text']").first.click()
```

However, I am not able to fill out the form.